# Docker ERROR: Container command not found or does not exist when running from Win10

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, boot2docker

This is driving me crazy...

I have Win10 and I have installed the Docker Toolbox with

```
Docker=1.10.2 
Compose=1.6.0 
VirtualBox=5.0.14
```

I have successfully launched the LAMP in Linux [Amazon linux] but when I try to do the same the terminal responds with **"ERROR: Container command not found or does not exist"**
As I understand, there is something wrong with the way Windows interpreter the CMD syntax.

I have tried

```
 - CMD ["/run.sh"]
 - ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]     
 - CMD /run.sh
 - CMD '/run.sh'
 - CMD run.sh
 - CMD "/run.sh"
```

but nothing seems to work.

*Note: When I run CMD /run.sh the error does not appear but the container exits immediately.*

*Note2: I have exactly the same problem when trying to setup the LAMP with Docker-Machine on AWS*

I have this **DockerfileLamp** :

```
FROM ubuntu

# -- Install needed packages --
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# -- Install additional utilities --
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y supervisor git curl apache2 mcrypt cron wget nano unzip

# -- Install PHP 5.5 --
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server-5.5 php5-mysql pwgen php-apc php5-mcrypt php5-xdebug php5-gd php5-curl php-pear openssh-server php5-cli php5-apcu php5-intl php5-imagick php5-json

# -- Set localhost to apache conf file --
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

# -- Add image configuration and scripts --
ADD ./lamp/start-apache2.sh /start-apache2.sh
ADD ./lamp/start-mysqld.sh /start-mysqld.sh
ADD ./lamp/run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod 755 /*.sh
ADD ./lamp/my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
ADD ./lamp/supervisord-apache2.conf 
    /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-apache2.conf
ADD ./lamp/supervisord-mysqld.conf 
    /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-mysqld.conf

# -- Remove pre-installed database --
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*
# -- Add MySQL utils --
ADD ./lamp/setup_MySQL.sh /setup_MySQL.sh
RUN chmod 755 /*.sh

# -- config to enable .htaccess --
##ADD apache_default /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# -- Environmental variables to configure php --
ENV PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE 10M
ENV PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE 10M

# -- Add volumes for MySQL --
##VOLUME  ["/etc/mysql", "/var/lib/mysql" ]

# -- Set up SSH server --
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:root' |chpasswd
RUN sed -ri 's/^PermitRootLogin\s+.*/PermitRootLogin yes/'
    /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -ri 's/UsePAM yes/#UsePAM yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
ADD ./lamp/supervisord-openssh-server.conf
    /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-openssh-server.conf

# -- Install Python & pip --
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y python python-pip python-dev && \
    pip install --upgrade pip
# -- Install xvfb --
RUN apt-get install -y xvfb   

EXPOSE 80 3306 22

CMD /run.sh
```

and the **run.sh** :

```
#!/bin/bash

VOLUME_HOME="/var/lib/mysql"

sed -ri -e "s/^upload_max_filesize.*/upload_max_filesize = ${PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE}/" \
    -e "s/^post_max_size.*/post_max_size = ${PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE}/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
if [[ ! -d $VOLUME_HOME/mysql ]]; then
    echo "=> An empty or uninitialized MySQL volume is detected in $VOLUME_HOME"
    echo "=> Installing MySQL ..."
    mysql_install_db > /dev/null 2>&1
    echo "=> Done!"  
    /setup_MySQL.sh
else
    echo "=> Using an existing volume of MySQL"
fi

exec supervisord -n
```

and the **docker-compose.yml** :

```
lamp: # apache + mysql/php
  build: .
  dockerfile: DockerfileLamp
  ports:
    - "8181:80"   # open apache to public
    - "3333:3306" # open mysql to public 
    - "2222:22"   # open SSH to public
```

Comment: I wonder if you should remove `exec` from the sh file, just use `supervisord -n`

Comment: On Linux it is not a problem but I will try it as I am out of options :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by simplifying the file. I commented out all the controls because whatever I tried it would keep throwing `Syntax Errors`

```
#!/bin/bash

VOLUME_HOME="/var/lib/mysql"

sed -ri -e "s/^upload_max_filesize.*/upload_max_filesize = ${PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE}/" \
    -e "s/^post_max_size.*/post_max_size = ${PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE}/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

#if [[ ! -d $VOLUME_HOME/mysql ]]; then
    echo "=> An empty or uninitialized MySQL volume is detected in $VOLUME_HOME"
    echo "=> Installing MySQL ..."
    mysql_install_db > /dev/null 2>&1
    echo "=> Done!"
    /setup_MySQL.sh
#else
#    echo "=> Using an existing volume of MySQL"
#fi

exec supervisord -n
```

It works for my case so I am not going to investigate further. Cheers!

**EDITED**

The above solution was not so complete.
It worked because I was making changes from INSIDE the container.

The permanent solution goes like this : 
I migrated the `run.sh` file to a private Gist . [It does not need to be private but ok]
I think the problem is that when I try to build the Dockerfile from Windows machine [either locally or on a cloud provider] it messes up the syntax , EOF , line breaks and whatnot.
So I broke out of it by ADDing the gist url

`ADD http://gist_url/run.sh /run.sh`

Note1: You must use the raw file URL otherwise you are going to get the complete HTML.

Note2: The private gist is not protected.You don't need authentication to fetch the URL.

Comment: I must also add that I had the same problem running it on  a MAC

Answer (score 1):

Docker is process centric, in other words your containers dies when your CMD script dies. At the end of your script run ...

```
tail -f logfile (where logfile is some logfile you are interested in)
```

This will

1 - stop your container exiting
2 - allow you to do

```
docker logs -f containerName
```

To help u debug

3 - allow you to enter into the container with

```
docker exec -it bash containerName
```

Then u can run the command that you think is failing inside the container and try n sort this out

Whilst this doesn't directly answer your question it should give u sufficient weaponry to attack this issue

Comment: Nice pointer danday74 ! I should have done it from the start. I debugged it from inside the container. The file was somehow saved in DOS format and not UNIX , and was throwing a syntax error. It had to do with EOF and return characters of some sort. I tried to convert it with dos2unix but didnt work. Finally I decided to just simplify the hell out of it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

For another [project](https://medium.com/@ivanermilov/scalable-spark-hdfs-setup-using-docker-2fd0ffa1d6bf#.7qfe17wt8) I tried to get to work on Windows with Docker Machine I ran into the same ambiguous error message of docker-compose `Container command not found or does not exist`.

Your comment about line endings triggered me to try `dos2unix ./*/*.sh` within `git-bash` (multiple scripts, in subfolders), which fixed the issue for me.

My suspicion is that `git clone` saves the files with DOS line endings, which results in incorrect syntax for the top line `!#/bin/bash`.

```
$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.6.2, build e80fc83

$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 21:49:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 21:49:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```